# Getting No such column error

Tags: android, sqlite

In the database of my Android App, I am trying to update the value of specific cell of the column but getting error `NO SUCH COLUMN`.

I am trying this query in my Database Handler class,

```
public void addVote(String politicianname,int vote)
{
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TOTALVOTES, vote);
    db.update(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, values, KEY_POLITICIANNAMES=politicianname, null);
}
```

This is where i am creating table,

```
String CREATE_POLLINGVOTES_TABLE="CREATE TABLE pollingvotes(politiciannames TEXT, totalvotes NUMERIC)";
db.execSQL(CREATE_POLLINGVOTES_TABLE);
```

This is where is adding names in `TABLE_POLLINGVOTES`,

```
public void addPoliticianNames() //This method is called before calling `addVote` Method
{
    deleteTable();
    String[] a = {"I","Me","Myself"};

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {

        values.put(KEY_POLITICIANNAMES, a[i]);
        db.insert(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, null, values);
    }
}
```

Here is my LogCat,

```
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: I (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE pollingvotes SET totalvotes=? WHERE I
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1563)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1514)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.example.polling.DBAdapter.addVote(DBAdapter.java:134)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.example.polling.VotePage.onClick(VotePage.java:42)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-31 05:35:45.463: E/AndroidRuntime(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
```

This is how my database looks,

[image]

Where I am getting wrong,

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code where you created the table?

Comment: Paste the whole failing query: `UPDATE pollingvotes SET totalvotes=? WHERE I` => Looks like something is missing in the code you've pasted

Comment: check what KEY_POLITICIANNAMES contains???

Comment: @ling.s: `KEY_POLITICIANNAMES` is a field name `private static String KEY_POLITICIANNAMES="politiciannames";`

And I have pasted the snap shot of my database.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall your application and install again.

Comment: I insist: What is the complete query you're running? If this is it `UPDATE pollingvotes SET totalvotes=? WHERE I` then your condition is messed up.

Comment: @MostyMostacho: I got my Solution :)

from Lawrence Choy's Answer!

Comment: Is there any way to add the value to that specific cell means if the cell value is 1 then next time if value is updating then it become 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.update(TABLE_POLLINGVOTES, values, KEY_POLITICIANNAMES + "='" + politicianname + "'", null);
```

You forgot to quote the `=` sign in the query.

Comment: @Lawrence Choy: Yeah! It works :)
Is there any way to add the value to that specific cell means if that cell value is 1 then next time if value is updating then it become 2 ?

Comment: @Shiv I always wanted to do the same thing, but couldn't find a good solution. I end up always fetching the current value first and then update it :)

Comment: @LawrenceChoy: hmm Let me find this on Google. We should Never end our hope :P ,
btw Thanks for the help :)